# Owebia grand total showing wrong after placed order

Tags: magento2

I use bellow code for shipping price will add 50% extra of grand total which is tax, subtotal, and discount, but It not working on Magento 2.3. It showing invalid grand total and shipping after place order but before that, it showing right on the frontend.

```
addMethod('test', [
   'title'      => "3 Days",
'enabled'    =>  $request->dest_region_id!= '52',
   'price'      => ($quote->grand_total)*.50,
]);
```

On magento 1x I have faced same issue but it fixed by using:

```
cart.price+tax+discount
```

But on Magento 2.3 I can't find the tax and discount.